# Tensorflow: labeling issue

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import glob
fq=glob.glob("*.jpg")
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(fq)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value,channels=3) 
my_img=tf.cast(my_img,tf.float32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(my_img, [50, 50])


labels=[1,1,1,0,0]
onehot = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=2)



image_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image], batch_size=2)

# layer 1
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2, 3, 52], stddev=0.01))
b1= tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape = [52]))
layer1=tf.nn.conv2d(image_batch,w1,[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
act1=tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(layer1,b1))
pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(act1,2,2)

# layer 2
b2= tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape = [104]))
w2=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2,52, 104], stddev=0.01))
layer2=tf.nn.conv2d(pool1,w2,[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
act2=tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(layer2,b2))
pool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(act2,2,2)

#fully connected layer
b3= tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape = [300]))
w3=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([12*12*104, 300], stddev=0.01))
fcl1=tf.reshape(pool2,[-1,12*12*104])
fcl1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl1, w3), b3)
fcl1 = tf.nn.relu(fcl1)
fcl1 = tf.nn.dropout(fcl1,0.5)

#output layer
b_out=b3= tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape = [2]))
w_out=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([300, 2], stddev=0.01))
ans=tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl1,w_out),b_out)


#traning , loss , optimizer
logits = ans
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
logits=logits, labels=onehot))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)




with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for step in range(1, 40):
        s.run(train_op)
        print(step,s.run(loss_op))
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 56, in 
>       logits=logits, labels=onehot))
>
> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 5 for 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' (op: 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [2,2], [5,2].

Please tell me what is my mistake, I think I need to feed 2 labels at a time but it is taking all 5 at a time. How can I batch labels separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making input batches, but not label batches. Try feeding label batches as well. Make a placeholder for your labels:

```py
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
# Keep the tf.one_hot op.
onehot = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=2)
```

and then later:

```py
all_labels = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
start = 0
with tf.Session() as s:
    # ...
    for step in range(40):
        t = all_labels[start:start+2]  # grab next label batch
        start += 2
        if start > len(all_labels):
            start = 0  # reset to start of list when we overrun the end
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={labels: t})
```

Honestly, I would handle both your data batches and your label batches the same way, but I was having trouble figuring out how to get `tf.train.batch` to work on the output of `tf.one_hot`, and I was having trouble running `tf.train.batch` on your raw label array first and then passing it to `tf.one_hot`.

Comment: thanks,worked  like a charm. you're a true hero!  people marked this question as "put on hold as off-topic" but i never demanded debugging but i wanted to clear my doubt so i thought posting my raw code would help people to understand my situation. i really appreciate your time!  thanks again :)